# Error while installing GLPK on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, glpk

I am trying to install `GLPK` on `Python 2.7.11 64-bit` version. I am running it on `Windows 10 Home 64-bit` and I already installed MS Visual C++ compiler package for Python 2.7 V9. I managed to install pulp and had no problem. But when try to install GLPK it gives me this error:

[image]

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try GCC to build GLPK libraries? Cygwin?

Comment: i just did and it gave me similar error.

Comment: `'glpk.h' : No such file or directory`, so the problem is your compiler cannot find glpk header. One way is to add your glpk folder to path. If you use gcc you can add `-I\path\to\glpk.h`. Also, it looks strange that windows uses visual c++ for python when compiling .c file.

Comment: Yes, glpk.h is missing. I couldn't resolve this issue as well. I tried to download tar file and then install it but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting `Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
Does anyone know a workaround for this?